# 404 Error for django serving static files. How to setup django to serve static files?

Tags: django, django-views

Settings.py file in Project directory :

I already added following :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

-> in template

```
<script src="{% static "validateurl/home.js" %}"></script>
```

I have a directory **static** under project directory. home.js is under **validateurl** directory under **static**.

Referring JS File using following in template html file :

[image]

Please advise what am I missing here.

Errors below :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to configure your django app to serve static files for **local** development.

The STATIC_ROOT default is None so you have to specify that in settings. Make sure you have something like this in your settings.py This tells your webserver where to find and serve the static file mapped to a url.

```
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Second also specify your STATIC_URL variable as it also defaults to none. following should suffice. This will be used for setting up the urlpattern.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

You need to have a url pattern so your server knows what url corresponds to the static files

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Specify STATICFILES_DIRS variable in settings. So that the collect static manager knows where to find statics and put them in the STATIC_ROOT. This can be an array or tuple of items to different directories. This can be empty if you have no additional directories

```
STATICFILES_DIRS =  (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pathtohomejsdirectory/'),)
```

Finally, make sure you run `python manage.py collectstatic`
This copies all the files specified in STATICFILES_DIRS over to the /static/ (STATIC_ROOT) directory to be served by django.

On a **production**, you want your webserver/reverse proxy say nginx or apache to serve the files. See here django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production)

Comment: thank you. where should i modify urlpatterns? in the main urls.py or the app urls.py file? do I need to run collectstatic for js files also? I don't have any images as of now in the project to display.

Comment: i would put it in the main urls.py as it is a configuration not only pertinent to an app.

Comment: Ok, I did. still the same error. STATICFILES_DIRS =  (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'validateurl/static/js/home.js'),) is this correct? my js file is in not in app directory.

Comment: go into django shell. import os. copy and paste that code. is it the accurate file path to home.js?  did you run python manage.py collectstatic?

Comment: I ran python manage.py collectstatic, but getting an error that the system cannot find the path specified. same error in django shell too!

Comment: It is working, I gave the full path of the windows directory and did python manage.py collectstatic, thanks a lot for your help.