# Cannot upload image to MEDIA_ROOT using Mongoengine ImageField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, imagefield

I'm trying to upload images using Mongoengine ImageField.
But after uploading a test image,I got page not found by visiting http://127.x.x.x:xxxx/media/testimage.png.

> Raised by:    django.views.static.serve
>   "/Users/xxx/Documents/basedir/media/testimage.png" does not exist

**myproject/settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**myproject/myapp/models.py**

```
from mongoengine import Document, ImageField

class Image(Document):
        image = ImageField(upload_to="")
        filename = fields.StringField()
```

**myproject/urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    #bla
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try using `UploadTo` class from the answer I posted to this question [UploadTo class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53732490/3980759). You are not setting properly the path to where the image must be saved.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Maybe because I'm using the ImageFiled from mongoengine and not from django.db models?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why don't you use Django Model instead of Document?

Comment: Because I'm using mongoengine to connect django with mongodb

Comment: Okay, so do you get the same result ? no images uploaded ! Or, you get different errors ? I think that fixing the path should solve it whether it's a model or a document using because at the end, it's always Django handling it for you.

Comment: Yes, I got the same error. I think this is because the __call__ function in UploadTo will no be called. I made a debug output inside this function and it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this. It is fairly thorough and provides every step needed to configure static files.  [404 Error for django serving static files. How to setup django to serve static files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560619/404-error-for-django-serving-static-files-how-to-setup-django-to-serve-static-f/52560826#52560826).  It appears you are definitely missing STATICFILES_DIRS and also have you ran `python manage.py collectstatic` command?

It would also be good to confirm you upload_to of the ImageField is also correct.  You can verify this in the shell. `python manage.py shell`