# Django ImageField is empty

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a form that uses ajax to create a new user. All the other fields work, besides the ImageField. I don't get a error when submitting, but the image will still not save.

Github Repo: https://github.com/VijaySGill/matching-app

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('matchingapp/', include('matchingapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    profileImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="profileimage", blank=True, null=True)
    hobby = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby, blank=False)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def registerUser(request):
         ...
        image = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=newUser)
        if image.is_valid():
            userprofile = image.save(commit=False)
            userprofile.user = request.user
            userprofile.save()
        ...
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

register.html

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                ...
                var fd = new FormData($("#profileImage").get(0));
                fd.append("username", $("#username").val());
                fd.append("email", $("#email").val());
                fd.append("password", $("#password").val());
                fd.append("firstName", $("#firstName").val());
                fd.append("lastName", $("#lastName").val());
                fd.append("gender", gender);
                fd.append("dateOfBirth", dob);
                fd.append("hobbies", JSON.stringify(selectedHobbies));

                if($("#password").val() == $("#confirmPassword").val()){
                $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url: '/matchingapp/registerUser/',
                        processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 data: fd,
                 ...
      });
```

forms.py

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profileImage',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the following method:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    profileImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="UploadTo('user_photo')", blank=True, null=True)
    hobby = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby, blank=False)
```

Where `UploadTo` is a class for saving your photos under a directory called `user_photo`  in your media folder.

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from uuid import uuid4

@deconstructible
class UploadTo(object):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.sub_path = path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        # get filename
        if instance.pk:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
        else:
            # set filename as random string
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        # return the whole path to the file
        return os.path.join(self.sub_path, filename)
```

This class will set properly the path to be used so that your photo can be found, because the problem is in the path you are passing to `upload_to`.

***Disclaimer***: the code above is not mine, but worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment, but I can't. How does the post data look like and is the image actually in there? 
You might wanna remove blank=True and null=True from the ImageField for testing purposes. Django should complain about the image not being there or something.

> if image.is_valid()

might return false and therefore not save the image